# Failed to load phpMyAdmin configuration (common.inc.php:467): parse error

Tags: phpmyadmin

Parse error: parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 467 <--- ---this is the error on the very last stage of installing php.Please help so that i can start up with my project.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version? and where did you get it?

Comment: hi marc, it is phpmy admin 4.7.5, on the website itself

Answer (score 0):

You need at least php 5.5 to get it running.